# File name with versions comparison in shell script

Tags: shell, sh, dos2unix

Suppose I have file names like *abc-1.0.sh,xyz-1.0.sh,pqr-1.0.sh,abc-2.0.sh, abc-3.0.sh.*

I am trying with array concept, but not able to do it.
I want file names as *abc-3.0.sh,xyz-1.0.sh,pqr-1.0.sh* only.
How should I do it in `.sh` file?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is the issue how to convert an array of filenames into a comma-separated string? I'm further confused by the inclusion of the `dos2unix` tag...

Comment: If you're on a system with GNU tools, look at `ls -v` and `sort -V` in the respective man pages.

Comment: @Kusalananda  i want it for consolidation .......not comma separated string but seprate array with latest/mentioned values above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a `bash` script (requires `bash` 4.3+) that does approximately what you're wanting to do:

```
filenames=( abc-1.0.sh xyz-1.0.sh abc-3.1.sh pqr-1.0.sh abc-2.0.sh abc-3.10.sh )

declare -A suffixes majors minors

for filename in "${filenames[@]}"; do
    stem=${filename%%-*}        # "abc-xx.yy.sh" --> "abc"
    suffix=${filename#*-}       # "abc-xx.yy.sh" --> "xx.yy.sh"

    # Figure out major and minor version from "$suffix"
    major=${suffix%%.*}         # "xx.yy.sh" --> "xx"
    minor=${suffix#*.}          # "xx.yy.sh" --> "yy.sh"
    minor=${minor%%.*}          # "yy.sh" --> "yy"

    if [ -z "${suffixes[$stem]}" ] ||
       [ "$major" -gt "${majors[$stem]}" ] ||
       ( [ "$major" -eq "${majors[$stem]}" ] &&
         [ "$minor" -gt "${minors[$stem]}" ] )
    then
        suffixes[$stem]=$suffix

        # Remember the largest parsed "xx.yy" for this stem
        majors[$stem]=$major
        minors[$stem]=$minor
    fi
done

for stem in "${!suffixes[@]}"; do
    printf '%s-%s\n' "$stem" "${suffixes[$stem]}"
done
```

This script outputs

```
pqr-1.0.sh
xyz-1.0.sh
abc-3.10.sh
```

It parses the filenames and extracts the *stem* (the bit before the dash) and the suffix (the bit after the dash), then it extracts the major and minor version from the suffix. It then uses a set of associative arrays, `suffixes`, `majors` and `minors`, to compare the version components with the previously found latest version for that particular stem.  If the stem has not been seen before, or if the version of the seen stem was lower, the arrays are updated with the information for that stem.

At the end, the consolidated data is outputted.

The restriction in this code is that the filename always is on the form

```
stem-xx.yy.something
```

and that `xx` and `yy` are always integers.

Comment: for i in `cat object.txt` ; do echo $i >> output.txt; grep -i -A 5 $i markingfile.log | egrep -i 'Object Name| Object Type' >> output.txt; done;